# How to set visibility of a group of views in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, visibility

I need to show one view or another in a single function.
Is there any way to do this without doing:

```
[label1 setHidden:YES];
[label2 setHidden:YES];
[label3 setHidden:YES];
```

e.g. in one function?

In android I would create two absolute layouts and show one or the other, I am searching something similar on iOS.

Comment: You can embed these views in a superView, link its outlet in your class and set this view hidden. 
In your XIB, you will select your views and click on `Editor`->`Embed in`->`View`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how i can embed them in a superView?

Comment: You can do it programmatically, initializing a UIView and adding those UILabel as subviews. Or with XIB, as I said you before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add those `UILabel` inside a `UIView`, and then when you need them to hide, you can set that `UIView` to be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You hide all subviews in a single line.
[view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHidden:)
              withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

Similarly if you want to remove all subviews  you can remove them in single line

[view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];